# What beer style would be good to enhance with Stevia rebaudiana?

Tags: ingredients, recipe, beer-styles

As we know it, [Stevia rebaudiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevia_rebaudiana) introduces herbal sweetness in form of calories-free, non-fermentable [steviol glycosides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steviol_glycoside). I'm tempted to use it with my beer, but I honestly have no idea where to start. Dark caramel beer would be dangerous, because herbal sweetness might go bad with caramel. So what style could use sweetness that has nothing to do with malty sweetens?

So far my best bets are sweet double AIPA, to match stevia with american hops, and rice beer (3kg malt, 2kg not malted rice) that has very low malty anything, and thus allows hops and spices to really show themselves.

Comment: My understanding is stevia sweetness is enhanced by the presence of other sweeteners. Why not start with something dry and lightly hopped? A Kölsch perhaps; it has some floral sweetness, but I find this style a tad astringent.   If you want something stronger, it sounds like a good idea in a dry mead. No flavor interference from hops, and the zests and spices used to flavor mead often aren't very sweet.

Answer (score 2):

an american milk stout

maybe a sour beer.

Brett beers, but brett, may eat some of the sweetner or convert them into unknowns....with weird flavors....(recently i found out brett ferments lactose and some hop compounds.)

Im sure there are others, but those are the ones that came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a stout, make it dryer than you usually would, and then add a little to sweeten it back to a balanced level.

Equally if you ever find you have an over attenuated beer that is lacking the balancing sweetness, you may try adding a little.

Answer (score 0):

How are you planning to introduce the stevia? Are you growing the plant and plan to extract yourself, buying it as a sweetner, etc?

If dried, then place in a hop bag with a lighter ale or lager in secondary and/or kegging. If fresh, then place fresh leaves in container with vodka for 36hrs to extract. Can either cook (but not boil) liquid to condense or simply add liquid to the secondary. Issue is stevia extract is green, so green beer...

Comment: This is not an answer... I have it dried and I have access to fresh plants.

Comment: Answer:  If dried, then place in a hop bag with a lighter ale or lager in secondary and/or kegging. If fresh, then place fresh leaves in container with vodka for 36hrs to extract. Can either cook (but not boil) liquid to condense or simply add liquid to the secondary.  Issue is stevia extract is green, so green beer...